# Creating a popup box using jQuery or Javascript that works for all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popupwindow

I have a code like following which displays a popup message correcly in my chrome browser, but I've tested it out on other browsers such as Firefox and Edge, this doesn't works, it just crates a weird looking box on the end of the page... The code is:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", 'data:text/plain,');
        document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
        if(window.frames[0].window.confirm("Are you sure you want to change brand state? Note: Changing brand state from Preview to Live will erase all data related to that brand.")) {
            $.post("/brand/updateBrandState", {
                'brandId': $(this).val(),
                "brandState": $(this).find("option:selected").text()
            }, function (data) {
                if (data == "ok") {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }else if(data=="empty") {
                    alert("Cannot change state from Live to Preview");
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }else if(data=="live") {
                    alert("Brand is now live!");
                }
            });
```

Can someone help me out to make it work on other browsers as well ??

Thanks !!

Edit:

now im using this html:

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"> 
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Check https://jqueryui.com/dialog/. You can customize the style as needed!

Comment: Yeah but how am I gonna check if user clicked "Ok" or "cancel" button on the dialog ? Could you post me a practical example ?

Comment: Check https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation. Try the various option on the right side with title  **Examples**. Click **view source** to check corresponding code.

Comment: just use the bootstrap popup which uses jquery

Answer (score 0):

For popup box, use [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Easy to use and supported by all browsers(that supports jquery).

**DEMO**

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Yes",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                //Do some Job
            },
        },
        {
            text: "No",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
        }

    ],
    open: function (event, ui) {
    //add some functionality or styling if you want
    },
    //same for close,drag,dragStart,dragStop,focus and all
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah but how am I gonna check if user clicked "Ok" or "cancel" button on the dialog ? Could you post me a practical example ?

Comment: Done, check :) @perkes456

Comment: Ow thanks, so basically now I shold just add a div tag with an id of #myDialog right and It will display these two buttons :) Where could I display the text (in which part) for the dialog? ^^

Comment: Yes and your div should contain the messages you want to show inside the pop-up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115317/discussion-between-perkes456-and-samghatak).

Comment: Hey um, I edited my first question with the HTML I'm using, but the popup has no X sign on it, its just an empty square lol

Comment: Not sure what might be the issue...works fine here:https://jsfiddle.net/9qe1rt1y/1

Comment: Did you add the css? https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css